# D3 selfnode link using d3.forcesimulation()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have two questions. First I using this example (http://bl.ocks.org/curran/9b73eb564c1c8a3d8f3ab207de364bf4) for creating d3 diagram and trying create selfnode link to same node, but i dont know how.

```js
var width = 960,
          height = 500,
          nodeSize = 20,
          arrowWidth = 8,
          svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
          linkG = svg.append("g")
          nodeG = svg.append("g")
          // Arrows are separate from link lines so that their size
          // can be controlled independently from the link lines.
          arrowG = svg.append("g");
      
      // Arrowhead setup.
      // Draws from Mobile Patent Suits example:
      // http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292
      svg.append("defs")
        .append("marker")
          .attr("id", "arrow")
          .attr("orient", "auto")
          .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
          // See also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute
          //.attr("viewBox", "0 -" + arrowWidth + " 10 " + (2 * arrowWidth))
          .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
          // See also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute
          .attr("refX", 10)
          .attr("refY", 0)
          .attr("markerWidth", 10)
          .attr("markerHeight", arrowWidth)
        .append("path")
          .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
      
      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink())
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
      
      simulation.force("link")
        .distance(140);
      
      var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);
      
      function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
        simulation.fix(d);
      }
      
      function dragged(d) {
        simulation.fix(d, d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
      }
      
      function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      }
      
      function render(graph){
        
        var link = linkG.selectAll("line").data(graph.links);
        var linkEnter = link.enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link-line");
        link.exit().remove();
        link = link.merge(linkEnter);
        
        var arrow = arrowG.selectAll("line").data(graph.links);
        var arrowEnter = arrow.enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "arrow")
          .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)" );
        arrow.exit().remove();
        arrow = arrow.merge(arrowEnter);
        
        var node = nodeG.selectAll("g").data(graph.nodes);
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").call(drag);
        node.exit().remove();
        
        nodeEnter.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "node-rect")
          .attr("y", -nodeSize)
          .attr("height", nodeSize * 2)
          .attr("rx", nodeSize)
          .attr("ry", nodeSize)
          .on("click", function (d){
            simulation.unfix(d);
          });
        
        nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("class", "node-text");
        
        node = node.merge(nodeEnter);
        
        node.select(".node-text")
          .text(function (d){ return d.name; })
          .each(function (d) {
          
            var circleWidth = nodeSize * 2,
                textLength = this.getComputedTextLength(),
                textWidth = textLength + nodeSize;
          
            if(circleWidth > textWidth) {
              d.isCircle = true;
              d.rectX = -nodeSize;
              d.rectWidth = circleWidth;
            } else {
              d.isCircle = false;
              d.rectX = -(textLength + nodeSize) / 2;
              d.rectWidth = textWidth;
              d.textLength = textLength;
            }
          });
        
        node.select(".node-rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.rectX; })
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.rectWidth; });
        
        simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);
        
        simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", function (){
          
          graph.nodes.forEach(function (d) {
            if(d.isCircle){
              d.leftX = d.rightX = d.x;
            } else {
              d.leftX =  d.x - d.textLength / 2 + nodeSize / 2;
              d.rightX = d.x + d.textLength / 2 - nodeSize / 2;
            }
          });
          
          link.call(edge);
          arrow.call(edge);
          
          node.attr("transform", function(d) {      
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });
        });
      }
      
      // Sets the (x1, y1, x2, y2) line properties for graph edges.
      function edge(selection){
        selection
          .each(function (d) {
            var sourceX, targetX, midX, dy, dy, angle;
          
            // This mess makes the arrows exactly perfect.
            if( d.source.rightX < d.target.leftX ){
              sourceX = d.source.rightX;
              targetX = d.target.leftX;
            } else if( d.target.rightX < d.source.leftX ){
              targetX = d.target.rightX;
              sourceX = d.source.leftX;
            } else if (d.target.isCircle) {
              targetX = sourceX = d.target.x;
            } else if (d.source.isCircle) {
              targetX = sourceX = d.source.x;
            } else {
              midX = (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2;
              if(midX > d.target.rightX){
                midX = d.target.rightX;
              } else if(midX > d.source.rightX){
                midX = d.source.rightX;
              } else if(midX < d.target.leftX){
                midX = d.target.leftX;
              } else if(midX < d.source.leftX){
                midX = d.source.leftX;
              }
              targetX = sourceX = midX;
            }
          
            dx = targetX - sourceX;
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
            angle = Math.atan2(dx, dy);
          
            // Compute the line endpoint such that the arrow
            // is touching the edge of the node rectangle perfectly.
            d.sourceX = sourceX + Math.sin(angle) * nodeSize;
            d.targetX = targetX - Math.sin(angle) * nodeSize;
            d.sourceY = d.source.y + Math.cos(angle) * nodeSize;
            d.targetY = d.target.y - Math.cos(angle) * nodeSize;
          })
          .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.sourceX; })
          .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.sourceY; })
          .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.targetX; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.targetY; });
      }
      
      var graph = {"nodes":["socks","shoes","shirt","belt","tie","jacket","pants","underpants"],"links":[{"source":0,"target":1},{"source":2,"target":3},{"source":2,"target":4},{"source":3,"target":5},{"source":4,"target":5},{"source":6,"target":1},{"source":6,"target":3},{"source":7,"target":6}]};
      
      graph.nodes = graph.nodes.map(function (d){
        return { name: d };
      });
      graph.links = graph.links.map(function (d){
        d.source = graph.nodes[d.source];
        d.target = graph.nodes[d.target];
        return d;
      });
      render(graph);
```

```css
.node-rect {
        fill: white;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
        cursor: move;
      }
      
      .node-text {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-anchor: middle;
        alignment-baseline: middle;
        pointer-events: none;
        /* Disable text selection
           from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting */
        -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
        -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
        -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none;
      }
      
      .link-line {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
      }
      
      /* Set the arrowhead size. */
      .arrow {
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.40.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/dhxc6fr3/ (selfnode has red color)
or (that is second question) is any way to change that weird moving element (nodes and links) over all canvas area? I mean, that the diagram would be generating in one place without this weird moving (I think is therefore, that coordinate is calculate in real time)

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first issue is that your working example is using `line` elements to draw the links while your second example (to draw the self-node link) is using paths.  You'll need to first modify working example to use `path` (since you can't draw curves with `line`).  Then, it's pretty trivial to check if it's a self-node with  `if (d.source === d.target)` and draw the link accordingly:

```
if (d.source === d.target){
 return "M" + sourceX + "," + sourceY + "A" + 40 + "," + 40 + " " + -45 + "," + 1 + "," + 0 + " " + (sourceX - 1) + "," + (sourceY + 1); 
} else {
  return "M" + sourceX + "," + sourceY + "L" + targetX + "," + targetY;
}
```

The "magic" numbers I chose to draw the curve were mostly deduced from trial and error to make the self-node curve look good.

Full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!--
    
      This program is a tool for visualizing small directed graphs.
      Inspired by:
        Force Dragging I
        http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2675ff61ea5e063ede2b5d63c08020c7
        Reactive Flow Diagram
        http://bl.ocks.org/curran/5905182da50a4667dc00
         
      Curran Kelleher May 2016
    -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Graph Editor</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.0.0-alpha.40.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style>
      
      .node-rect {
        fill: white;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
        cursor: move;
      }
      
      .node-text {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-anchor: middle;
        alignment-baseline: middle;
        pointer-events: none;
        /* Disable text selection
           from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting */
        -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
        -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
        -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
        -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
        user-select: none;
      }
      
      .link-line {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
        fill: none;
      }
      
      /* Set the arrowhead size. */
      .arrow {
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
        fill: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      
      var width = 960,
          height = 500,
          nodeSize = 20,
          arrowWidth = 8,
          svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
          linkG = svg.append("g")
          nodeG = svg.append("g")
          // Arrows are separate from link lines so that their size
          // can be controlled independently from the link lines.
          arrowG = svg.append("g");
      
      // Arrowhead setup.
      // Draws from Mobile Patent Suits example:
      // http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292
      svg.append("defs")
        .append("marker")
          .attr("id", "arrow")
          .attr("orient", "auto")
          .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none")
          // See also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute
          //.attr("viewBox", "0 -" + arrowWidth + " 10 " + (2 * arrowWidth))
          .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
          // See also http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#MarkerElementRefXAttribute
          .attr("refX", 10)
          .attr("refY", 0)
          .attr("markerWidth", 10)
          .attr("markerHeight", arrowWidth)
        .append("path")
          .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
      
      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink())
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
      
      simulation.force("link")
        .distance(140);
      
      var drag = d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended);
      
      function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
        simulation.fix(d);
      }
      
      function dragged(d) {
        simulation.fix(d, d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
      }
      
      function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      }
      
      function render(graph){
        
        var link = linkG.selectAll("path").data(graph.links);
        var linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "link-line");
        link.exit().remove();
        link = link.merge(linkEnter);
        
        var arrow = arrowG.selectAll("path").data(graph.links);
        var arrowEnter = arrow.enter().append("path")
          .attr("class", "arrow")
          .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)" );
        arrow.exit().remove();
        arrow = arrow.merge(arrowEnter);
        
        var node = nodeG.selectAll("g").data(graph.nodes);
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g").call(drag);
        node.exit().remove();
        
        nodeEnter.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "node-rect")
          .attr("y", -nodeSize)
          .attr("height", nodeSize * 2)
          .attr("rx", nodeSize)
          .attr("ry", nodeSize)
          .on("click", function (d){
            simulation.unfix(d);
          });
        
        nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("class", "node-text");
        
        node = node.merge(nodeEnter);
        
        node.select(".node-text")
          .text(function (d){ return d.name; })
          .each(function (d) {
          
            var circleWidth = nodeSize * 2,
                textLength = this.getComputedTextLength(),
                textWidth = textLength + nodeSize;
          
            if(circleWidth > textWidth) {
              d.isCircle = true;
              d.rectX = -nodeSize;
              d.rectWidth = circleWidth;
            } else {
              d.isCircle = false;
              d.rectX = -(textLength + nodeSize) / 2;
              d.rectWidth = textWidth;
              d.textLength = textLength;
            }
          });
        
        node.select(".node-rect")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.rectX; })
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.rectWidth; });
        
        simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);
        
        simulation.nodes(graph.nodes).on("tick", function (){
          
          graph.nodes.forEach(function (d) {
            if(d.isCircle){
              d.leftX = d.rightX = d.x;
            } else {
              d.leftX =  d.x - d.textLength / 2 + nodeSize / 2;
              d.rightX = d.x + d.textLength / 2 - nodeSize / 2;
            }
          });
          
          link.call(edge);
          arrow.call(edge);
          
          node.attr("transform", function(d) {      
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
          });
        });
      }
      
      // Sets the (x1, y1, x2, y2) line properties for graph edges.
      function edge(selection){
        selection
          .attr("d", function (d) {          
         
              var sourceX, targetX, midX, dy, dy, angle;

              // This mess makes the arrows exactly perfect.
              if( d.source.rightX < d.target.leftX ){
                sourceX = d.source.rightX;
                targetX = d.target.leftX;
              } else if( d.target.rightX < d.source.leftX ){
                targetX = d.target.rightX;
                sourceX = d.source.leftX;
              } else if (d.target.isCircle) {
                targetX = sourceX = d.target.x;
              } else if (d.source.isCircle) {
                targetX = sourceX = d.source.x;
              } else {
                midX = (d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2;
                if(midX > d.target.rightX){
                  midX = d.target.rightX;
                } else if(midX > d.source.rightX){
                  midX = d.source.rightX;
                } else if(midX < d.target.leftX){
                  midX = d.target.leftX;
                } else if(midX < d.source.leftX){
                  midX = d.source.leftX;
                }
                targetX = sourceX = midX;
              }

              dx = targetX - sourceX;
              dy = d.target.y - d.source.y;
              angle = Math.atan2(dx, dy);

              // Compute the line endpoint such that the arrow
              // is touching the edge of the node rectangle perfectly.
              sourceX = sourceX + Math.sin(angle) * nodeSize;
              targetX = targetX - Math.sin(angle) * nodeSize;
              sourceY = d.source.y + Math.cos(angle) * nodeSize;
              targetY = d.target.y - Math.cos(angle) * nodeSize;
              
           if (d.source === d.target){
              return "M" + sourceX + "," + sourceY + "A" + 40 + "," + 40 + " " + -45 + "," + 1 + "," + 0 + " " + (sourceX - 1) + "," + (sourceY + 1); 
            } else {
              return "M" + sourceX + "," + sourceY + "L" + targetX + "," + targetY;
            }       
           
          });
      }
      
      var graph = {"nodes":["socks","shoes","shirt","belt","tie","jacket","pants","underpants"],"links":[{"source":0,"target":1},{"source":2,"target":3},{"source":2,"target":4},{"source":3,"target":5},{"source":4,"target":5},{"source":6,"target":1},{"source":6,"target":3},{"source":7,"target":6},{"source":7,"target":7},{"source":1,"target":1},{"source":2,"target":2},{"source":3,"target":3},{"source":4,"target":4},{"source":5,"target":5},{"source":6,"target":6}]};
      
      graph.nodes = graph.nodes.map(function (d){
        return { name: d };
      });
      graph.links = graph.links.map(function (d){
        d.source = graph.nodes[d.source];
        d.target = graph.nodes[d.target];
        return d;
      });
      render(graph);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

For your second question, see this example [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139).  The key lines are:

```
// See https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#simulation_tick
for (var i = 0, n = Math.ceil(Math.log(simulation.alphaMin()) / Math.log(1 - simulation.alphaDecay())); i < n; ++i) {
  simulation.tick();
}
```

This essentially just runs the simulate to completion before rendering the graph.